In which Pink Panther film does Clouseau go back to jail repeatedly?
Which is the Pink Panther film in which Clouseau get sent back to jail repeatedly, after disguising himself as an artist, or something similar, and painting, with an easel? The scene is outside a jail or a hospital, and Clouseau gets himself arrested, about three to four times. In one scene, he has even balloons sticking out of the van that he was arrested in! 

Sounds like A Shot In The Dark from 1964, the 2nd film in the Pink Panther series. From Wiki:

[Clouseau] is himself arrested [by the] police four times in quick succession (first for selling balloons without a license, then for selling paintings without a license, then for hunting without a license, and finally with Maria Gambrelli for public nudity, after they flee a nudist community).

You can see him arrested for selling balloons and paintings here at 2:37:




Probably why the OP could not find it, as this movie was not a "Pink Panther" movie (this was the first, and the series had not yet been so designated. It's actually kind of odd that even though there are several of the same characters, this movie is almost never listed as a PP movie)

The Pink Panther - 1963. A Shot in the Dark - 1964.

A Shot In The Dark is actually the 2nd film in the Pink Panther series
